# Generate code for core data attributes in xcode 4

Tags: core-data, xcode4, datamodel

In xcode 3 there was a helpful feature in the data model builder where you could highlight some attributes/relationships in an entity, right-click, and choose to copy method and property declarations to the clipboard. (You could choose if you wanted objective-c 2.0 property declarations also). Then you could paste them into your NSManagedObject subclass.

I see how you can still generate the entire class file; but this isn't helpful if you are adding attributes to an existing entity. Have they removed this feature from xcode 4? I used it all the time!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the Core Data Model Editor Help: [Creating Objective-C Accessor Methods for a Managed Object](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_accessors.html)

Comment: Thanks. That works, but it's kind of annoying. How are you supposed to know that the regular "edit>copy" command would actually do that? In Xcode 3 there was a specific option to do that. Plus, it no longer copies the headers for the CoreDataGeneratedAccessors category.

Comment: It's not perfect, but not that the Special Paste menu item reflects the context (Interfaces, Implementations).

Comment: That's true, but it breaks the principle of discovery. At the point you are looking for the feature (and generation of code is a different feature to copying) there is no way to discover it.

Comment: It is not working on Xcode 4.2. Back to square zero again. BTW, I hate Xcode 4. It is the crappiest app Apple ever created. It is a leap backwards compared to Xcode 3.

Comment: Works like a charm in Xcode 4.3.2. Excellent! Only gripe: It's not available via the context-sensitive menu (via Option-Click). That would be a nice touch.

Comment: For over a year I was too lazy to look up what happened from Xcode 3-4, and today I finally decided to look. Thank you so much for posting. :)

Answer (score 5):

You may find [MoGenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) useful.

Answer (score 2):

Watch out for the fact that the special paste menu item only appears in the Edit menu not the contextual menu in the source editor.