# XCode 4 Accessor Implementation

Tags: core-data, xcode4, accessor

In XCode 4, how do I access the "Copy Method Implementation to the Clipboard", which was available in XCode 3?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Generate code for core data attributes in xcode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327600/generate-code-for-core-data-attributes-in-xcode-4).

Comment: Actually, this is a duplicate (I had searched for most of those terms but with "accessors", not attributes).  What's the proper thing to do with this post?  Delete it (if that's possible)?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure myself, but I think Stack Overflow etiquette says to leave the question undeleted – even if it's already answered elsewhere, your phrasing of the question may make it easier for the next person to find it while searching. It may also be desirable to create an actual answer below, to remove the question from the "unanswered" list, so I'll go ahead and do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Generate code for core data attributes in xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327600/generate-code-for-core-data-attributes-in-xcode-4) for the answer – XCode 4 made this feature much harder to find, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, Scott.  You have fully answered my question.